# How can I log didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo? - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, ios10

I'm working with Firebase SDK, and I having a trouble with handling push notifications in Swift 3.0.

Everything seems works fine, except for the managment of the data.

I just wanna log my app when receives remote notifications ( so NON ACTIVE ), is it possible?

Xcode closes everything that is related to the app when it is closed, but I need to know what is happening once app is killed, to manage my remote push notification data!

**UPDATE**

I get that didReceiveRemoteNotification is never called, but notifications are shown.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not getting called is because your application is closed, not running in either background or foreground. `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called when your app is running either on background or foreground. It is also called when user taps the received notification. So in your case you should use `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` instead of the `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. Check out this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application) for further info.

Comment: Yep but how can I log what it say to me?

Console of Xcode 8.0 doesn't show me anything

Comment: Well you can't see it on console because your app will be closed. My suggestion would be storing the values in UserDefaults and then debugging it that way. If you application is not closed you can just use this `print(userInfo)`.

Comment: My king! How did i not think about it ?

Thanks a lot!